# How to forward requests to apps from one project to another in django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project A with 2 apps currently. One is a fruits app and another an auth app.
When a user logs in to `http://myip/auth/login`, a log in message is displayed based on a successful or an unsuccessful attempt. The user can then access `http://myip/auth/fruits` which displays all fruits in the system.

There is another standalone Django project B that was written by another author which deals with vegetables. I want my project to act like a proxy for the vegetables project which has many more apps. When a user requests `http://myip/auth/vegetables`, I want my app to forward the request to the vegetable app in the other project.

Please note that these are two different projects and they have two different settings files. Project A connects to 2 databases and Project B to one. They are all different.

Please tell me how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want this redirect to happen in the background? If so, you have some juggling to do with Python's requests library. If not, you can use the redirect as per dm03514's answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are only interested in redirection you can use the built in [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function which wraps [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('http://myip/auth/vegetables')
```

Comment: How can I run two projects at the same time? I'm using the built in webserver that django comes with.

Comment: You run two projects with two instances of `runserver` (while in dev mode), and with two vhosts in either Apache or nginx while in production.